# How to add a ID or a class to slider background image in slider revolution

Tags: slider, revolution-slider

Im trying to change the background image of slider revolution using media queries. I want to change the image to a different one for mobile devices. Is there a way to do this within slider revolution editor? So far I couldn't find any setting to do that.

If not, is there a way to add an ID or a class to the background image of the slider?

thanks!
T

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the method from this article https://www.sliderrevolution.com/faq/display-different-images-on-different-screen-sizes/ to achieve what you needed there.